# Views block element with Panels viewes

Tags: views, blocks, panels

I have a content type **foo**, that has a media field and a body with text. I want to list the most resent **foo** on  whit a specific visualization: double column layout for a foo that has media which is previewed left and on the right is a summery of the body. If there is no media then simply show the summary of the body.

I can create a block **bar** in *Views* module, that list all the **foo** and show this block on .
I can create a Node template of type **foo** with *Panels* module that has the required layout but I don't know how to apply that on the list of **foos** in **bar**.

Do I need to use in Panels *Node template*?
My selection rule is: `This panel will be selected if NOT (media is set to ""), and Current path is "front".` (not working).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a special layout only here, maybe the display suite module is enough for you. 
The main part of the solution is you have to create a view mode for the node, that you will use to display a media/description in the views. 
You have to set the proper layout here, so something 50/50 and the two fields. If you are done with this new view mode, you have to go into the views. In the **Format** section you will see the **Show** line there you have to change from Field to Content. If you set the Content you will see a second column which is listing the available view modes for your content, here you need to select the recently created view mode.